# Collecting payment using bank account token in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with Stripe

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, asp.net-core-webapi, payment-gateway

I have successfully generated a token using bank account details within my Angular application, see code below.

```
const result = await this.stripe.createToken('bank_account', {
      bank_account: {
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'usd',
        account_holder_name: 'any name',
        account_number: '000123456789',
        routing_number: '110000000',
      },
    });
```

I'm now attempting to pass this token to my C# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with the goal of creating a `PaymentIntent` and collecting payment. Kindly guide me through the process of utilizing this bank account-generated token to achieve payment collection within my API.

I am leveraging the Stripe.API NuGet package v43.7.0.

Comment: Token is legacy integration. I'd recommend checking the guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=API) for the payment integration of ACH direct debit, i.e. US bank account.